# how to validate particular input field using angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I am trying to validate some input fields using angularJS. I found some example. But they are validating entire form.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-required="true" />
        <input type="password" ng-model='password' ng-required="true" />
        <button ng-click="myform.$valid && preview()">Preview</button>
        <button ng-click="myform.$valid && update()">Update</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

and controller code is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name=undefined;
    $scope.preview = function(){
        alert("Previewed");
    };
    $scope.update = function(){
        alert("Updated");
    }
});
```

The above code validating the fields based on form name. But I wanted to know is there any way to validate that particular input field ?

Comment: There are many ways, but is exactly the desired result?

Comment: With validating, you mean validating if your inputs content is for e.g. a number, a particular string, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gikovi/1/edit?html,output)
Yes you can, you must specify a `name` for the input like

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" name='name' ng-model='name' ng-required="true" />
        <input type="password" ng-model='password' ng-required="true" />
        <button ng-click="myform.$valid && preview()">Preview</button>
        <button ng-click="myform.$valid && update()">Update</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

then you can check if the `name` is valid with `myForm.name.$valid`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/acvjd1hw/).

Just add a `name` to the `input` filed and follow the same as you did to the `form`.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-required="true" name="txtName" />
        <input type="password" ng-model='password' ng-required="true" />
        <button ng-click="myform.$valid && preview()">Preview</button>
        <button ng-click="myform.$valid && update()">Update</button>
        <div>Status of name: <span style="color: blue">{{myform.txtName.$valid}}</span></div>

    </form>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = undefined;
    $scope.preview = function () {
        alert("Previewed");
    };
    $scope.update = function () {
        alert("Updated");
    }
});
```